# Why is a function type required to be "wrapped" for the type checker to be satisfied?

Tags: haskell, type-mismatch, type-systems, automatic-differentiation

The following program type-checks:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Numeric.AD (grad)

newtype Fun = Fun (forall a. Num a => [a] -> a)

test1 [u, v] = (v - (u * u * u))
test2 [u, v] = ((u * u) + (v * v) - 1)

main = print $ fmap (\(Fun f) -> grad f [1,1]) [Fun test1, Fun test2]
```

But this program fails:

```
main = print $ fmap (\f -> grad f [1,1]) [test1, test2]
```

With the type error:

```
Grad.hs:13:33: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Integer’
                     with ‘Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s Integer’
      Expected type: [Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s Integer]
                     -> Numeric.AD.Internal.Reverse.Reverse s Integer
        Actual type: [Integer] -> Integer
    • In the first argument of ‘grad’, namely ‘f’
      In the expression: grad f [1, 1]
      In the first argument of ‘fmap’, namely ‘(\ f -> grad f [1, 1])’
```

Intuitively, the latter program looks correct.  After all, the
following, seemingly equivalent program does work:

```
main = print $ [grad test1 [1,1], grad test2 [1,1]]
```

It looks like a limitation in GHC's type system.  I would like to know
what causes the failure, why this limitation exists, and any possible
workarounds besides wrapping the function (per `Fun` above).

(Note: this is not caused by the monomorphism restriction; compiling
with `NoMonomorphismRestriction` does not help.)

Comment: Could this be the dreaded monomorphism restriction?

Comment: It is not the monomorphism restriction.

Comment: This is indeed a limitation in the type system. The failing program would required impredicative types to be type-checked correctly (`[test1,test2]::[forall a . ...]` is impredicative), which as the [docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#impredicative-polymorphism) claim, GHC only has "extremely flaky support" for. The best workaround is a `newtype` wrapper. Alternatively, turn on `ImpredicativeTypes` and add type annotations to each subterm of the program until it typechecks.

Comment: I've also just remembered that `ad` has several modules to address precisely this limitation in GHC, e.g. for [`diff`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad-4.3.4/docs/Numeric-AD-Rank1-Forward.html#v:diff).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an issue with GHC's type system. It is really GHC's type system by the way; the original type system for Haskell/ML like languages don't support higher rank polymorphism, let alone impredicative polymorphism which is what we're using here.

The issue is that in order to type check this we need to support `forall`s at any position in a type. Not only bunched all the way at the front of the type (the normal restriction which allows for type inference). Once you leave this area type inference becomes undecidable in general (for rank n polymorphism and beyond). In our case, the type of `[test1, test2]` would need to be `[forall a. Num a => a -> a]` which is a problem considering that it doesn't fit into the scheme discussed above. It would require us to use impredicative polymorphism, so called because `a` ranges over types with `forall`s in them and so `a` could be replaced with the type in which it's being used.

So, therefore there's going to be some cases that misbehave just because the problem is not fully solvable. GHC does have some support for rank n polymorphism and a bit of support for impredicative polymorphism but it's generally better to just use newtype wrappers to get reliable behavior. To the best of my knowledge, GHC also discourages using this feature precisely because it's so hard to figure out exactly what the type inference algorithm will handle.

In summary, [math](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007298000475) says that there will be flaky cases and `newtype` wrappers are the best, if somewhat dissatisfying way, to cope with it.

Comment: `ImpredicativeTypes` is not actually supported in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 3):

The type inference algorithm will not infer higher rank types (those with `forall` at the left of `->`). If I remember correctly, it becomes undecidable. Anyway, consider this code

```
foo f = (f True, f 'a')
```

what should its type be? We could have

```
foo :: (forall a. a -> a) -> (Bool, Char)
```

but we could also have

```
foo :: (forall a. a -> Int) -> (Int, Int)
```

or, for any type constructor `F :: * -> *`

```
foo :: (forall a. a -> F a) -> (F Bool, F Char)
```

Here, as far as I can see, we can not find a principal type -- a type which is the most general type we can assign to `foo`.

If a principal type does not exist, the type inference machinery can only pick a suboptimal type for `foo`, which can cause type errors later on. This is bad. Instead, GHC relies on a Hindley-Milner style type inference engine, which was greatly extended so to cover more advanced Haskell types. This mechanism, unlike plain Hindley-Milner, will assign `f` a polymorphic type *provided* the user explicitly required that, e.g. by giving `foo` a signature.

Using a wrapper newtype like `Fun` also instructs GHC in a similar way, providing the polymorphic type for `f`.